# Objective-Zip file folder structure ios

Tags: ios, compression, directory-structure

I have my App create a file, compress it into a .zip file, then attach it to an email.  But the .zip file contains many directories before the actual file.  Starting with the '/' which is a nameless folder and looks invisible to the people receiving it.  The top level directory is '/', the next level is 'com'...
/var/mobile/Applications/CDA16BB231BDABABBA/Documents/data.txt

How can I remove all the directories and have the .zip file contain only the file?

Here's the code I have used...

```
    NSError *error;
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];
    NSLog(@"string to write:%@",printString);
    [printString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES
                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    ////ZIP FILE/////

    NSString *zipfilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.zip"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: zipfilePath error: &error];

    ZipFile *zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc]initWithFileName:zipfilePath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];

    NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:zipfilePath error:&error];
    NSDate *Date = [attributes objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];

    ZipWriteStream *stream = [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:filePath fileDate:Date compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [stream writeData:data];
    [stream finishedWriting];


    [zipFile close];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are saying:

```
writeFileInZipWithName:filePath
```

The variable `filePath` contains that huge long name you are complaining about. It is the whole path from the top all the way down to your actual file.

Your file's name is `@"data.txt"`, so what you want to say is:

```
writeFileInZipWithName:@"data.txt"
```

Comment: The complaining has stopped.  Thanks!

Comment: It's confusing, because what you don't realize at first is that the "name" is just a name. You can assign an arbitrary name to the file inside the zip. The *data* comes from the ZipWriteStream, but the *name* is up to you.